How to create a Mentions ("@Mentions" or "#hash") Tools with the help of tribute.js with Editor.js?
I'm currently working an application, In which I'm implementing the text editor using Editor.js. But I'm stuck with implementing @mention functionality in it.
Here are tribute js and editor.js
This is the class I have created,
import Tribute from "tributejs";

class CustomMentionTool {
  static get isInline() {
    return true; // This tool is an inline tool
  }

  constructor({ data, api }) {
    this.api = api;
    this.data = {
      value: data.value || "",
    };
    this.wrapper = null;
    this.tribute = new Tribute({
      // Configure Tribute.js options here (e.g., values, selectTemplate, etc.)
      values: [
        { key: "John Doe", value: "john_doe", name: "John Doe" },
        { key: "Jane Smith", value: "jane_smith", name: "Jane Smith" },
        // Add more users or data as needed
      ],
      selectTemplate: function (item) {
        return `@${item.original.name}`;
      },
      requireLeadingSpace: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    this.wrapper = document.createElement("span");
    this.wrapper.contentEditable = false;
    this.wrapper.textContent = this.data.value;
    this.wrapper.classList.add("mention");

    // Attach Tribute.js to the wrapper element
    this.tribute.attach(this.wrapper);

    return this.wrapper;
  }

  save() {
    return {
      value: this.wrapper.textContent,
    };
  }
}

export default CustomMentionTool;

In editor class,
const editor = new Editor({
...,
tools: {
   mention: { class: CustomMentionTool },
 }
})


Hey, what did you tried so far? Any piece of code or struggle specifically?

Hey @kissu, I have updated my code above, Please check

So, what is not working exactly? Btw, tribute is quite an un-maintained project so some things might not work well.
